# How to enable python on Vim version 8 for Mac

Tags: macos, vim

I just upgraded to the vim version 8.0.142 on my mac Yosemite. However some of the plugins that I am using need python on compilation, when I run `:echo has('python')` command I am getting `0`. I did some research and some people suggested that using `vim-nox` packages in Ubuntu fixed their issue but as I mentioned I am using Mac and I could not find an equivalent package.

Comment: How did you install Vim? Does `:echo has('python3')` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install Vim.

Once Homebrew is installed, you can install vim with:

```
brew install vim
```

Then Vim with python support will be in `/usr/local/bin/vim` on Intel or `/opt/homebrew/bin/vim` on Apple Silicon.

Comment: Hey Dan this is not installing the vim 8.0 it has the older version

Comment: @click On my system it's Vim 8.0.0142. Are you sure you're running the homebrew vim and not the system one? It will leave the system Vim in place (/usr/bin/vim) and that will not be upgraded.

Comment: can you specify what version of homebrew you are using.
I am using `Homebrew 1.1.5-127-g538028a` and this version is trying to install vim-7.4.1910

Comment: @click I am using brew 1.1.6.

Comment: there is no --with-python3 flag

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Not anymore, yeah... Python 3 is now the default because Python 2 is EOL. I'll update the answer.